# Higher Order Differential Equations

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

2 Equations in the higher order differential equations which both are non-homogenous, I am tasked to solve them using complimentary equations.

From what I am given, the 2nd equation uses partial derivatives to solve it further. So far, I am at a roadblock since the two equations now have trigonometric functions in them.

I need to find the general and particular solution for both. I kindly ask for a step-by-step analysis for future references as well as a reviewer for my upcoming final examination.

Here are the equations:-

1. $(D^2+2D+2)y=e^{-x}\csc(x)$
2. $(D^2-2D+1)y=\frac{e^{-x}}{(e^x+1)^2}$

Comment: What have you tried? Have you been able to make any progress on the homogeneous equations as a starting point? Also, what do you suspect would be the approach for the particular solution? (Unfortunately, variation of parameters is where I'm thinking we go with this, but have you been taught this method?)

Comment: Well I only get the basic concept of the variation of parameters, the use of the exponential notation. I am still confused on the approach after that, As far as I can do, it's that the D's will turn to m's, and get the value of m by reverse foil method.

Comment: You're kind of there. The $D$s turn to $m$ because you use the substitution $y = e^{mx}$ for the homogeneous equation. So for instance the first one becomes $$(m^2+2m+2 = (m+1)^2+1 = 0$$
and the second becomes $$(m^2-2m+1 = (m-1)^2 = 0$$
See if you can take it from there for the homogeneous equations and then we can talk about the particular. Edit your question with these.